# WCF service Appdomain details

Tags: asp.net, wcf, appdomain

I am reading WCF book.It states that the client can consume service running on same AppDomain or different application Domain.

Suppose I am creating a service in IIS localhost.

example

```
localhost\TestService\Service.svc (WCFService Website).
```

and my client is in

```
d:\demo\client (windows form)
```

- Does it mean client is running on
  different AppDomian and Service is
  running on  different Appdomain?
- How can i have client and service
  both running on same AppDomain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

The book is saying that it's *possible* to have the service and client in the same AppDomain, not that it's *necessary*, or even possible in all cases.

An example would be if your windows forms application was hosting a service and also calling the same service.